# Angular2: best practice for getting values from a QueryList of inputs

Tags: angular

so I create a list inputs:

```
template: `        
        <div *ngFor="#item of m_checkboxes">
          <label class="pull-left">{{item.name}}</label>
          <Input #checkInputs type="checkbox" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)" [checked]="item.checked" value="{{item.value}}" class="pull-left" style="margin-right: 2px">
        </div>
```

and I create a QuestList of the inputs via:

```
  @ViewChildren('checkInputs')
  inputs:QueryList<any>
```

and when any one of the checkboxes of the inputs is clicked I map loop over the Observables, but I am forced to go into NativeElement to grab the checked value and I feel there must be a better way...

this is what I do now, which works... but is it best practice?

```
 private onChange(value) {    
        this.inputs.map(v=>{
            console.log(v.nativeElement.checked); // grab value from native :-(
        });

    }
```

thanks

Sean

Answer (score 2):

Rather than inspecting the DOM elements, I think it would be better to inspect the data - the values of `item.checked`, wherever those are in your components. If the reason you're inspecting the DOM is to update the data values, that's what two-way data bindings are for. I believe simply changing `[checked]="item.checked"` to `[(ngModel)]="item.checked"` will make the binding two-way so Angular2 will update your data values for you.

Comment: I am just trying to stay away from 2 way bindings, as I will be creating 10 checkboxes per table record and could have potentially 500 records, so that would 5000 2 way bindings... any other suggestions? tx Sean

Comment: @born2net Why are you trying to stay away from 2 way bindings? I would be very **very** surprised if your custom homemade solution has better performance than the one specifically made for the purpose by the Angular team, regardless of how many bindings there are.

Comment: well, my thinking is that with my onChange I do a single map and I am done, but with 2 way it has to keep track of these possible 5000+ mem locations... and if that's the best way, fine...but wanted to know of any other way besides 2 way to get status on these dynamically created Inputs... tx, Sean.

Comment: @born2net Your "single map" is not a fast or high performance operation. It has to scan over each and every one of the 5000 checkboxes, and does so each and every time any one of them is changed. With two way data bindings, on the other hand, when one changes Angular 2 has the direct reference handy and updates that one value, and that's it. A two way binding runs in constant time. Your map will run in time proportional to the number of checkboxes.

Comment: well, come to think of it, my underline data structure is Immutable.js Map, so 2 way binding won't work, since I can't bind directly to that type of object, correct?

Comment: @born2net ...and you're using it to track data that you specifically expect to change? Change it to a mutable map, of course.

Comment: no the underline data is already an immutable Map.. and yes I use it for tracking. I double checked now and doing the 2 way binding via [(checked)]="item.checked" did not update my underline structure in the Map (well actually it's a List() not a Map.. but same idea).

Comment: and to complicate things further, you can't really modify an Immutable list (the underline data structure) as it would break its contract.. so once again, I am not sure 2 way binding would even work here...

Comment: I opened a diff Q for the binding issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35857056/angular2-2-way-binding-not-updating-the-underline-data