# Angular2: 2 way binding not updating the underline data

Tags: angular

this I would imagine this is supposed to work:

```
  @Component ...
    ...
    <div *ngFor="#item of m_checkboxes">
        <Input #checkInputs type="checkbox" [(value)]="item.value">
    </div>
    ...

  constructor(){
    var self = this;
    setInterval(()=>{
        console.log(self.m_checkboxes);
    },3000)
}
```

but inspecting the timer, the underline data structure is not mutating when I click on the checkbox (and wait 3+ sec)...

I know I can use ngModel but I am trying to get [(prop)] working instead of ngModel.

My unlderline data is basically an array of:

```
    this.m_checkboxes = [{checked: true}, {checked: true}];
```

I almost think this is not supported as I couldn't find a single example online of 2 way binding with non ngModel :/

thoughts?

regards

Sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're using the wrong property. It should be `checked`, not `value`.

Second, having just now tried it out, it seems that you actually have to use `ngModel`. The two-way binding syntax is specified in a general way not specific to ngModel, but the `checked` property does not have the associated `checkedChange` event that would be needed for it to work.